# SAPUI5: Adding routes dynamically throws error

Tags: sapui5

I want to add some routes dynamically to router. But it throws the following error:

> A name has to be specified for every route
>   - EventProvider sap.ui.core.routing.Router  A @ sap-ui-core.js:88

The code that I used is as following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < aRoutes.length; i++) {
    var _name = aRoutes[i].name,
        _pattern = sPatternPrefix + aRoutes[i].pattern,
        _target = aRoutes[i].target;
    var oRoute = new sap.ui.core.routing.Route(oRouter, {
        name: _name,
        pattern: _pattern,
        target: _target
    }); 
    oRouter.addRoute(oRoute, oParent);
}
```

What could be the reason, While all `name` parameter has a valid string?

The error is not thrown when the Route is created, but it's thrown when I want to use `addRoute` function.

Comment: You did you get the reference to the oRouter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a `Route`. Just use the oConfig object as it described in the [api](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.routing.Route.html#constructor) of `new sap.ui.core.routing.Route`. Thus change your code like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < aRoutes.length; i++) {
     oRouter.addRoute({
          "name" : aRoutes[i].name,
          "pattern" : sPatternPrefix + aRoutes[i].pattern,
          "target" : aRoutes[i].target
      }, oParent);
 }
```